# Is there a way to know when an element pass over another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky element which needs to recognize when it passes over another element in order to disappear from the screen.

This is the element that should disappear:

```
.sticky-footer
    .container
        .row.sticky-row
            .col-xs-6
                // text
            .col-xs-6
                // text
```

When the user is scrolling down and it passes over this element:

```
hr#line-before-related-article
```

Is there a way to do that with css or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen on an event that fires every time the page is scrolled and then check if it's location is past your hr#line-before-related-article.

Here's an example:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() >= $('#line-before-related-article').position().top) {

        $('.sticky-footer').hide();

    } else if ($('#line-before-related-article').position().top >= $(this).scrollTop()) {

        $('.sticky-footer').show();
    }
})
```

If you want something that's a little more performant, you can use something called a debounce function...

> For those of you who don't know what a debounce function does, it limits the rate at which a function can fire. A quick example:  you have a resize listener on the window which does some element dimension calculations and (possibly)  repositions a few elements.  That isn't a heavy task in itself but being repeatedly fired after numerous resizes will really slow your site down.  Why not limit the rate at which the function can fire?

More on that here:  https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: It's the root DOM element: `$(this) == $(document);`

Comment: Super weird. The sticky element disappear when I start scrolling down.

Comment: I did it already. Actually I had to change `$(document)` and put `$(window)` instead. What I should do now is restart the operation so when the user scrolls to the top, the sticky element comes again.

Comment: I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: You could something like this: `($('#line-before-related-article').position().top >= $(this).scrollTop())`